# Minimax algorithm for connect 4 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, minimax

I was trying to create a minimax ai to play against a human player in the game connect 4. I wrote the minimax function and it's helper functions, but when I tested it, it returned seemingly random values or wins for players when there is no possible win in a certain amount of moves.

I tried checking the recursive calls and the way the program is executed compared to pseudocode examples, but nothing looks different. I expect the code to always return -10 if it is the blue player's turn and the blue player has already had 3 in a line, and 10 if it is the red player's turn and the red player has already had 3 in a line.

A problem which sometimes occurred is that the minimax function would output infinity or -infinity.

Heres the code:

```
      function Disc(player, x){
        this.player = player;
        this.x = x;
        this.draw = function(){
          c.beginPath();
          c.arc(this.x, 31, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
          c.fillStyle = player;
          c.fill();
          c.stroke();
          c.fillStyle;
        }
        this.lock = function(board){
          for(rowsDetect = 0; rowsDetect < rows; rowsDetect++){
            if(board[rowsDetect][Math.floor(this.x / 70)] != "white"){
              board[rowsDetect - 1][Math.floor(this.x / 70)] = this.player;
              return;
            }
          }
          board[rows - 1][Math.floor(this.x / 70)] = player;
        }
      }

      function availSpots(board){
        availableSpots = [];
        for(i = 0; i < columns; i++){
          if(board[0][i] == "white"){
            availableSpots.push(i);
          }
        }
        return availableSpots;
      }

      function isWin(board, player){
        for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
          for(j = 0; j < columns - 3; j++){
            if(
              board[i][j] == player &&
              board[i][j + 1] == player &&
              board[i][j + 2] == player &&
              board[i][j + 3] == player
            ){
             return true;
            }
          }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < rows - 3; i++){
          for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            if(
              board[i][j] == player &&
              board[i + 1][j] == player &&
              board[i + 2][j] == player &&
              board[i + 3][j] == player
            ){
              return true;
            }
          }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < rows - 3; i++){
          for(j = 0; j < columns - 3; j++){
            if(
              board[i][j] == player &&
              board[i + 1][j + 1] == player &&
              board[i + 2][j + 2] == player &&
              board[i + 3][j + 3] == player
            ){
             return true;
            }
          }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < rows - 3; i++){
          for(j = 3; j < columns; j++){
            if(
              board[i][j] == player &&
              board[i + 1][j - 1] == player &&
              board[i + 2][j - 2] == player &&
              board[i + 3][j - 3] == player
            ){
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      function isTerminalNode(node){
        return isWin(node, "blue") || isWin(node, "red") || availSpots.length == 0 //is a tie;
      }

      function minimax(node, depth, maximizingPlayer){
        let availableSpots = availSpots(node);
        if(depth == 0 || isTerminalNode(node)){
          if(isWin(node, "red")){
            return 10;
          } else if(isWin(node, "blue")){
            return -10;
          } else if(availSpots.length == 0){
            return 0;
          }
        }

        if(maximizingPlayer){
          value = -Infinity;
          for(col = 0; col < availableSpots.length; col++){
            boardCopy = [];
            for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
              boardCopy.push([0]);
              for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                boardCopy[i][j] = node[i][j];
              }
            }

            let pieceCopy = new Disc("red", /*x value of scenario where disc is put*/availableSpots[col] * 70); /*multiplied by 70 because in actual game
when placed it needs to draw piece
as well for x value, so x
value is divided by 70 then floored
to get its column*/
            pieceCopy.lock(boardCopy);
            value = Math.max(value, minimax(boardCopy, depth - 1, false));
          }
          return value;
        } else {
          value = Infinity;
          for(col = 0; col < availableSpots.length; col++){
            boardCopy = [];
            for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
               boardCopy.push([0]);
               for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                 boardCopy[i][j] = node[i][j];
              }
            }
            // lock function is to drop on connect 4 board

            let pieceCopy = new Disc("blue", availableSpots[col] * 70);
            pieceCopy.lock(boardCopy);
            value = Math.min(value, minimax(boardCopy, depth - 1, true));
          }
          return value;
        }
      }
```

Comment: You variables should **all** be declared properly with `let` or `var`, including the loop index variables.

Comment: Can you give some examples, because with the for-loop variables i'm trying it with, it freezes up the website while running.

Comment: `let i, j;` in other words. That's called a **declaration**. You've got them for some variables, but they **all** should be declared.

Comment: Where is `.lock` method defined?

Comment: @zer00ne It is defined in the disc constructor, I will post the code. Lock method is on the top.